# Multiview and MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using a Multiview Control, in each View, the content is long and with a lot of different buttons and Gridviews, I would like to keep the scroll position in each View when a control inside does a postback,  since now it goes back to the begining of the View. I tried to use MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" but nothing happens. Do you know any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry was my error, all my content was inside a Panel, It seems that MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback doesnt work with Panel scrolls, I just have to take out the content from it.